# Issues creating a SharePoint REST api POST request to upload an image and metadata

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, picture-library, image-upload

I am trying to upload an image to a photo document library, currently I seem to get authorization errors when trying to post data but my user account has read and write access to the library, would you be able to help me identify the correct endpoint and code required for the upload?

Current strategy:

```
var arrayBuffer = getFileBuffer();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: http://example.example.com/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('photoLibrary'),
    type: "POST",
    data: arrayBuffer,
    processData: false,
    headers:{
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the URL to

`http://example.example.com/sites/mysite/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('photoLibrary')/RootFolder/Files/Add(url='<file name>', overwrite=true)`

replacing `<file name>` with the name of the file you're uploading.